# how to use value inside "data._value_here_.text.title"

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all sorry about the title. I have a problem where I'm having same data in multiple languages. For example data.jpn.text or data.eng.text. I'm getting the current language  value from my flutter app state. The weird problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to utilize that current language value.

I've tried for example data[currentLanguage].text or data.currentLanguage.text or data.$currentLanguage.text but I can't figure out which way is the correct way to use that state value to change all texts depending on the current language. Any help in this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the data is stored, and if you are facing issues with the syntax. So in the example below I have assumed data to be stored as a map. JSON can be treated as a map as well.

```dart
const lang_map={
  'eng':{
    'title':'Hello'
  },
  'hindi': {
    'title':'Namaste'
  }
};

const lang='hindi';

void main(){
  print(lang_map[lang]!['title']); // Output- Namaste
  // The '!' mark is because of null safety

}
```

You cannot use the dot '.' notation in Dart unless you have mapped the map to a Dart Class(Plain Old Dart Class). A good tool to generate these classes is [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/).

What you are trying to achieve is called Internationalization, i18n in short. While your solution may work for a small project, it is better to use packages to implement it. You can read more about i18n [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). An easy tutorial for i18n can be found [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/i18n-extension-flutter-b966f4c65df9).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I'm facing syntax problems exactly. And I have mapped them into a dart class. But still, i'm not sure how to use that data.currentLang.text (same as data.eng.text or data.jpn.text). And this is exactly my problem. Would you be able to tell how I'll be able to use the syntax in that format? I'm aware about I18n stuff, but still project is as you mentioned very small, So I've opted for the simpler json based internationalization for now. If it was any bigger, I would use I18n. Thanks for pointing out Quicktype as well!

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to achieve, trying to get a string to behave as a variable can work. What you can do instead is have a variable currentLang= data.eng and get your text as currentLang.text. If you want to change the language, do currentLang= data.jpn inside setState or equivalent depending on your state management